# python - "Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index. from ipykernel import kernelapp as app"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, compiler-errors

```
menu_sub= menu[menu["Trans Fat"]==0][menu["Cholesterol (% Daily Value)"]==0][menu["Cholesterol (% Daily Value)"]==0]
```

returns: "Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index. from ipykernel import kernelapp as app"

After searching for a solution people suggested I used '&', but after using that I get a other error..

```
menu_sub= menu[menu["Trans Fat"]==0 & menu["Cholesterol (% Daily Value)"]==0 & menu["Cholesterol (% Daily Value)"]==0]
```

returns: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Is there a way to do this in one line? or do have to create 3 different lines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you were chain boolean slicing where the boolean series you were slicing with were based off of the original and the slices you were chaining kept getting smaller.

Second, you need to wrap your boolean series in parentheses.

```
menu_sub= menu[
    (menu["Trans Fat"] == 0) &
    (menu["Cholesterol (% Daily Value)"] == 0) &
    (menu["Cholesterol (% Daily Value)"] == 0)
]
```

But now you can see you are repeating one condition twice, which I don't understand.

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks!! and for the repeating condition.. that was a fault in my typing needed an other condition here.. still thanks for the help, I just could'nt find the solution

Comment: @MarkWekking Upvote or accept the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of future readers. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote